# connecting to Android studio with a noSQL db like crouchDB

Tags: android, database, android-studio

Has anyone here ever used a db like `crouchDB` to connect to an android application? 
How do you connect to `crouchDB` using `Android Studio`?

I looked it up on google, but there was nothing there about this topic.

Comment: You want to connect android studio to noSQL DB or crouch DB

Comment: @KenKwok crouchDB :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with couchDB but as far as I know, you need to connect to a server which connects to a database in order to fetch data for android application. PHP is the most popular server side language and I learnt node.js for android application. For node js, I found [this](http://nodeexample.blogspot.hk/2012/04/asa.html) example that teaches you how to connect nodejs to couchDB may help you. Also, you may try different framework with nodejs to facilitate your work, such as loopback. Loopback contains a [connector](https://github.com/mattange/loopback-connector-couch) to connect to couchDB but there would be quite a lot to learn since you have to learn loopback and nodejs but loopback automatically provides rest api and android sdk for you to output data effectively. For PHP, you may google one of many tutorial websites that fit your need. I personally never used couchDB before and I learnt how to connect android application to database from [this tutorial](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/).